# Fragment Exit animation gets drawn on toolbar (Pre-lollipop)

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation

I'm having an issue when a custom enter and exit animation runs during fragment transactions on pre-lollipop devices.

Entering Fragment fades in and exiting animation is similar to a card fleeing to the right while rotating.

**on Pre lollipop**

[image: Exit Animation on pre lollipop]

**on Lollipop and above**

[image]

On lollipop and above, the animation works great but on pre-lollipop devices, as you can see, Text and the background color of the exiting fragment is seen on the custom Toolbar. And it stays there at least the entered fragment is touched.

Here is the exit animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="150%"
        android:pivotY="200%"
        android:toDegrees="60" />

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="20%"
        android:toYDelta="20%" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.1" />
</set>
```

Can you guys let me know about the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Try to put `<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />` to that activity.

Comment: It didn't solve the issue.